# Galaxy 5: GPS always stops working after phone has been in standby

Tags: gps, samsung-galaxy-5, standby

My new Samsung Galaxy 5 (also named Galaxy i5500, and running  (android 2.1) has some GPS issue.

The GPS works fine (i.e. it can find satellites when I use the app [GPS Test](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest).) directly after powering up my phone. However, as soon as the phone has been in standby, the GPS no longer can find any satellites. After restarting the device, the GPS is working again until the next standby.

The device has been upgraded to the latest firmware using Samsung Kies, and following Samsung's support advice I have already performed a factory reset.

Is there something that can be done to fix this (apart from waiting for Samsung Support's follow-up)?

**Edit**: I *think* this [androidforums post](http://androidforums.com/epic-4g-support-troubleshooting/179689-gps-cache-problem-workaround-tested-working.html) describes the problem and solution (still have to test it) quite well.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself but the following supposedly helps in getting a *faster* lock for Samsung's Galaxy range of Android devices.

Make sure GPS satellite and Wireless networks has been activated.

```
Press *#*#1472365#*#*. This will bring up GPS settings.
Settings -> Parameter Settings -> Address -> Server Type: 1x MPC
Settings -> Parameter Settings -> Position mode: option3
Settings -> Fix Request Settings -> Session Operation: Standalone
Settings -> Fix Request Settings -> Server Option: Local
gpsOne XTRA -> Xtra Enable: Enable
```

Then try with Google Maps.

If you want to go back to the default setting:

```
Settings -> Parameter Settings -> Address -> Server Type: UMTS SLP
Settings -> Parameter Settings -> Position mode: option2
Settings -> Fix Request Settings -> Session Operation: MS-based
Settings -> Fix Request Settings -> Server Option: Default
```

See if that helps. Other users have also reported issues with the Galaxy range of not receiving SMS messages immediately after returning out of Airplane Mode. Seems a touch buggy...

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I thought it solved it, but not sure anymore. Couldn't find any satellites after a couple of hours waiting.